# How to 'expand all' in Aptana Studio 3's code folding feature

Tags: php, aptana3, code-folding

In Aptana Studio 3, I have noticed that you can perform the following operation.

Right click on some code in a document > Commands > Source > Folding > Toggle Foldings at Level > All Levels

However, instead of toggling the folding I wish to explicitly ensure that All Levels are Expanded (no matter what their initial state is).

How is it possible to tell Aptana to somehow remove code folding and just 'Expand All Levels'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

To 'expand all':

1. Ensure you can see the line numbers in the Aptana PHP editor window.
2. Right-click on a line number.
3. A context menu appears.
4. Choose:

   Folding > Expand All (Ctrl+Numpad_Multiply)

All code in the document is expanded.